# Sqlite, sort second column without messing the order in the first

Tags: database, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
15|flex        |2|low   |Not started
16|flex        |1|medium|Not started
17|flex        |2|medium|Not started
18|gridonly-med|1|low   |Not started
19|gridonly-med|2|low   |Not started
20|gridonly-med|4|low   |Not started
21|gridonly-med|1|medium|Not started
22|gridonly-med|2|medium|Not started
23|gridonly-med|4|medium|Not started
```

and what I need is to sort it(desc) by 3-rd column without messing column 2 and column 4.

Basically, I need to get this table:

```
15|flex        |2|low   |Not started
17|flex        |2|medium|Not started
16|flex        |1|medium|Not started
20|gridonly-med|4|low   |Not started
19|gridonly-med|2|low   |Not started
18|gridonly-med|1|low   |Not started
23|gridonly-med|4|medium|Not started
22|gridonly-med|2|medium|Not started
21|gridonly-med|1|medium|Not started
```

I have tried:

```
ORDER BY column4 DESC, column1 ASC
```

but it didn't work.

I get:

```
23|gridonly-med|4|medium|Not started
20|gridonly-med|4|low   |Not started
22|gridonly-med|2|medium|Not started
19|gridonly-med|2|low   |Not started
17|flex        |2|medium|Not started
21|gridonly-med|1|medium|Not started
18|gridonly-med|1|low   |Not started
16|flex        |1|medium|Not started
```

If someone points out any clause or any other thing which I could use to solve my issue I would really appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must sort first by `col2`, then by `col4` and finally by `col3` descending:

```
ORDER BY col2, col4, col3 DESC
```

Note that I use the fact that `'flex'` is sorted alphabetically before `'gridonly-med'` and `'low'` is sorted alphabetically before `medium`, so if there were different values the code would not work.

For certain results you should use conditional sorting:

```
ORDER BY col2 = 'flex' DESC, 
         col4 = 'low' DESC, 
         col3 DESC
```

or:

```
ORDER BY CASE col2 WHEN 'flex' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
         CASE col4 WHEN 'low' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
         col3 DESC
```

and you can extend the branches of the `CASE` expressions to include more values.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=009c116bd249e25ed5ce709cfc90496e).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In my case **flex**  is not sorted alphabetically, neither does **low**.  
**col2** and **col4** are not sorted and should remain as they were. Is there any way to achieve that? 
Also, there are thousands of rows in my DB so I assume conditional sorting wouldn't help.

Comment: @armstrove I provided a demo where you can see that my query works and provides your expected results. If this is not what you get then you did not provide correct sample data. Use my demo with your actual data and post here the link that shows the results that you get.

Comment: [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f2b0ee12bc721106b8d2888953cea7fe) is the link, I just modified the `"flex"` to `"zflex"` and `"medium"` to `"amedium"`. And I need to get the result you got in your demo with the first `SELECT`.

`15 zflex 2 low Not started
17 zflex 2 amedium Not started
16 zflex 1 amedium Not started
20 gridonly-med 4 low Not started
19 gridonly-med 2 low Not started
18 gridonly-med 1 low Not started
23 gridonly-med 4 amedium Not started
22 gridonly-med 2 amedium Not started
21 gridonly-med 1 amedium Not started`

Comment: @armstrove This is why I provided 2 more solutions which you must adjust to your actual data. See this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a14bde20d3ee50cb804c534b2aaa5f10 The 3d query is more extended to cover more cases.

Comment: Thank you very much.